# Typescript .js.map files missing when publishing to azure

Tags: visual-studio-2012, azure, typescript

When I publish my web app to Azure website, using the Publish functionality in VS2012, none of the .js.map files are published with it.

What can I do to make sure those files are published to the server?

Comment: Are you trying to debug the JavaScript/Typescript after publishing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure they are added to the solution. Use the show all files feature followed by add file feature in the solution explorer to do this

Comment: is it not the idea that publishing should take care of it? Why remove the js files in the first place if I have to add them again (0.9.1.1) (i have the problem with the .js files)